# Ember view height

Tags: html, ember.js, height, footer

I'm trying to get the root view for my Ember application to have full (100%) height, unsuccessfully so far.

Why do I need that? I have a footer which I want aligned to the bottom even if the page content doesn't fill the whole height. To that end, I have the following CSS:

```
.push {
  height: 60px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
}
```

And HTML (using Twitter Bootstrap):

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="push"><!--//--></div>
    <div class="container">
  <!-- page content -->
    </div>
    <div class="push"><!--//--></div>
  </div>
  <footer>Copyright ... 2013</footer>
</body>
```

This works great without Ember. Now, introducing Ember:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="push"><!--//--></div>
    <div class="container">
  {{outlet}}
    </div>
    <div class="push"><!--//--></div>
  </div>
  <footer>Copyright ... 2013</footer>
</script>
```

And now it no longer works!

The damn thing inserts a `<div id="emberXYZ" class="ember-view">` which contains the whole thing, which by itself is quite fine, except that div doesn't have full height and the footer just hangs in the middle of the page right after the content.

I googled around for a solution, but couldn't find anything that would allow me to work around this problem. My guess is the simplest way would be to have Ember set the root view to 100% height (can't seem to find how to do that), but maybe there's some other clever trick that will accomplish what I want. Whatever solution that is, I'd need it to be at least IE8-compatible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not `.container > div { min-height: 100%; }` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. If `content` already has min-height set to 100%, the problem isn't `container`. The problem is the ember-view div that doesn't take the full height.

Comment: Oh, you mean the application view. App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({classNames:['my-class']})

Comment: You have to be kidding me! Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for! Where on earth was it documented that App.ApplicationView referred to the root view??

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem trying to get sticky footers to work with Ember JS and Bootstrap. As you noted the issue lies with Ember JS creating the view within a container `div` that does not get the 100% height.

As Ember only renders 1 immediate child `.ember-view` to the `<body>` (i.e. the Application view). We can use this CSS which will work in browsers, including IE8.

```
/* Works in all browsers, does not effect other views within your application */
body > .ember-view {
    height: 100%;
}
```

It does not effect any `.ember-view`'s that are subviews within your application because they will not be direct children of your page `<body>`.

Comment: Apparently these 2 solutions don't work. Neither does the simple .ember-view{height:100%}. I can see the ember-view class div in the inspector though. Any ideas ?

Comment: Just to let people know, this solution worked for me. For Ember v1.11, I first had to override the default ember rootElement Ember.Application.create. Then set my rootElement to 100% width and height. After that the above solution worked right away.

Comment: Regarding the first solution, I think 'first-of-type' selector cannot target elements by class names?

Comment: @jurer Thanks for pointing that out, I must have just got lucky with it when I tried. I've simplified the answer to use the universal solution of `body > .ember-view`

Answer (score 6):

If you define the application view you can then customize things like the class:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ["ember-app"]
})
```

You can then define your css:

```
.ember-app {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is the ember way.

Answer (score 0):

Here i can do give two answers which are not actually related to Ember.JS
1) How to set root element of EMberApp height to 100% -- You don't need to do any tweaks in Ember App code. In CSS, just set ember-view class height to 100%.

```
.ember-view {
 height: 100%;
}
```

if you want to avoid other views using this styling, you can use the id of view as u here specified one `emberXYZ`.

But your actual requirement is 
2) Making footer take only bottom of the page-- You can actually make footer `absolute` and set the `bottom` value to `0`.

```
footer {
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Unfortunately, for 1), setting the height in the ember-view class will mess with all other views and the XYZ part in the id is dynamic (it could be solved this way, but I'd need to find a way to add a fixed id to the root Ember view -- doesn't seem to be documented). 

For 2), using absolute placement is kinda cheating. Any way I could do this without absolute, but in a way that would work better than the above with Ember?

Comment: To assign a specific element ID to an ember view, you an set the `elementId` property. Obviously, per HTML, it must be unique on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this problem and it took me some time to fix it and I just wanted to share my solution with you guys.

"ember-cli": "2.13.1"
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6"

So as [user510159](http://stackoverflow.com/users/510159/user510159) wrote the problem lies with the ember-view class that is being set.

The solution from [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1295344/scott) to add the `height: 100%;` property to the ember-view class is half of the solution.

```
/* Works in all browsers, does not effect other views within your application */
    body > .ember-view {
    height: 100%;
}
```

For it to work in my case I had to set the height properties for the inner `div` elements of my html.

```
<div class=ember-view>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

sccs:

```
#header {
    height: 20%;
}

#content{
    height: 70%;
}

#footer {
    height: 10%;
}
```

I hope this helps.