# Ember full height div

Tags: css, ember.js

I've tried several methods in order to solve this, but I haven't succeeded. Ex: [Ember view height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643287/ember-view-height)
Even if I inspect the body with the class `ember-application`, or the inner div with the class `ember-view`, I still see the fixed height that is lower than 100%. So what causes this ?

**index.html**

```
...
<body>
... some script declarations....
</body>
...
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
<header>
...
</header>

<main>
{{outlet}}
<main>

<footer>
...
</footer>
```

**styles/app.css**

```
....
.ember-view {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Resulting HTML inspected through Chrome dev tools**

```
<html data-ember-extension="1">
    <body class="ember-application">

    ... scripts from body

    <div class="hiddendiv common"></div>

    <div id="ember286" class="ember-view">

    <header>
    </header>

    <main>
      <div class="container">
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
    </footer>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not to use flexbox?

```
.ember-application {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

LE: Close enough. Actual solution:

```
body > .ember-view
{
  display:        flex;
  min-height:     100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main
{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm already using Materialize lib that uses flex itself from what I understood. Anyway, tried your code, didn't change anything.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for the idea though. Added solution to your answer.